# How to display yes/no attribute in custom product grid in Magento?

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.8

I am creating a new custom product grid which will show a custom yes/no attribute.

I have successfully displayed the value of yes no which is saved in database in 0,1 format.

[image: need to show yes/no value]

But I need yes or no to be shown in data field.

I have used below code in my Grid.php

[image]

Please help guys.

Comment: show relevant codes instead of images

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Solved it.

here is code to show yes/no input type attribute in product grid.

```
$this->addColumn('yesno',
            array(
                    'header'=> Mage::helper('catalog')->__('yesno'),
                    'width' => '50px',
                    'align' => 'right',
                    'index' => 'yesno',
                    'type'=>'options',
                    'options' => array('1' => 'Yes', '0' => 'No')
            ));
```

Sorry for images instead of code.

Comment: Just a note that @Aleksandr's answer below is an improvement on this as it correctly uses the core's yes/no source model to generate the options instead of manually creating the array.

Comment: Yes exactly. So in case, you want a custom key you can create an array.

Comment: Except in this case there is no custom key/value pairs. You've just manually created the output of the system_config_source_yesno source model. Which is why Aleksandr's answer below is better.

Comment: @Brian agreed. But in case I want custom keys then it is good. I can manipulate easily.

Answer (score 8):

Try use

```
    $this->addColumn('yes/no', array(
        ...
        'type'      => 'options',
        'options'   => Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/system_config_source_yesno')->toArray(),
        ...
    ));
```

Comment: This should actually be `toArray()` not `toOptionArray()` for use in a grid option list.